# How to trigger unit testing from Laravel Artisan

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I have a situation where i have some unit tests with PHPUnit, and i want to trigger them from the artisan console utility of laravel. I have googled and i have not found any reference, Is it possible?  I am not asking how to test artisan commands. or how to dynamically call another artisan command, but to trigger unit tests from artisan

I can call certain commands using Artisan facade like

```
Artisan::call('migrate'); //which calls migration
```

like this is there a way i can call unit tests? I am using PHPUnit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 dynamically run migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953783/laravel-5-dynamically-run-migrations)

Comment: no its not duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use symfony's `process` command, which drives Laravel's artisan command under the hood anyway:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

$process = new Process('phpunit');
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
shell_exec('/path/to/phpunit/ /path/to/tests')
```

Comment: but how do i call the exec from Artisan? which was the real question

Comment: @ShobiPP this will work from anywhere, why don't you want to use it in Artisan command?