# Call php artisan migrate using Artisan

Tags: php, laravel-5, dynamic, laravel-artisan

Is it possible to create an Artisan call or command for

```
php artisan migrate
```

like `Artisan::call('migrate);`

So i can migrate missing tables to my database when connection is changed dynamically.

```
  Config::set('database.connections.dynamicdb', array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql', 
         'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
         'database'  =>  $database_name,
         'username'  =>  'test_user',
         'password'  =>  '123456',
         'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
         'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
         'strict'    => false,
         'options'   => [                                
               \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
            ]
       ));

  Artisan::call('migrate');
```

Or is there a way to create a command for it? Please suggest some solution.

Comment: You answered your own question - `Artisan::call('migrate')`. Have you tried that? Are you having issues with it?

Comment: It doesnt work. Mine is laravel 5.6

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". What happens? What errors or behavior do you get?

Comment: Ohk i will tell you the scenario. 

I have used a middleware to change connection dynamically and after config is set to the users database  , I run the artisan command. It doesnt show error.

Comment: Does the page "hang" and just sit there? You might need to pass the `--force` if this is in production; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953783/laravel-5-dynamically-run-migrations.

Comment: `Artisan::call('migrate', array('--path' => 'app/migrations', '--force' => true));`

I ran this command while login still doesnt work.

Comment: You likely also need to tell it to do `--database dynamicdb`. You continue to say "doesn't work" without indicating what happens - whether you get an error, a never-ending loading indicator, or it just continues on as if it had succeeded.

Comment: ` \Artisan::call('migrate', array('--path' => 'app/migrations', '--force' => true , '--database' => 'dynamicdb'));` 

I run this command. It doesnt show any error. Still not migrated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code:

```
\Artisan::call('migrate',
 array(
   '--path' => 'database/migrations',
   '--database' => 'dynamicdb',
   '--force' => true));
```

Because my default it takes **/app** as path and the migrations are placed in database/migrations. So this will work as it worked for me when creating new project.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Artisan;

Artisan::call('migrate', 
[
   '--path' => 'database/migrations',
   '--database' => 'dynamicdb',
   '--force' => true
]);
```

You can call the Artisan command from anywhere.
This is worked in Laravel 10.x