# How can i delete a migration that is not found?

Tags: laravel

#### I have this problem

when i run `php artisan migrate:refresh`:

```
Rolling back: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Rolled back:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (1.71ms)
Rolling back: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Rolled back:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (1.76ms)
Migration not found: 2018_06_30_113500_create_comments_table <---- THIS ONE!!!
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (8.18ms)
```

#### I had already tried:

`php artisan migrate:refresh`

`php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1` until I got: `"Migration not found: 2018_06_30_113500_create_comments_table"`

#### How can I delete this:

migrationfile `"2018_06_30_113500_create_comments_table"` ?

Comment: Did you check version history? Did someone forgot to check-in the file `2018_06_30_113500_create_comments_table`?

Comment: @MaartenDev this migration file belonged to a corrupt package. I have already removed the package and the git branch I tried it on no longer exists.

Comment: did you unregister the package too?

Comment: @MaartenDev first removed from composer.json then composer install. Then removed the entire vendor folder and composer install again.

Comment: did you try clearing the `migrations` table in the database?

Comment: @MaartenDev no. not yet. should i probably do it?

Comment: delete just the `2018_06_30_113500_create_comments_table` row in `migrations` table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239617/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-maartendev).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871413/safely-remove-migration-in-laravel, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558543/remove-specific-migration-in-laravel, ...

Answer (score 4):

This can be fixed by manually removing the `2018_06_30_113500_create_comments_table` record in the `migrations` table. You could use the following command:

```
DELETE FROM migrations where name = '2018_06_30_113500_create_comments_table'
```