# How to prevent some migrations in Laravel from being rolled back?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-migrations

Let's say I use Laravel 5.7 with Passport, and while I'm developing, I create migrations for my models, then I create Clients and tokens data in Passport tables. Now the migrations table looks like this :

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| id | migration                                                    | batch |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| 34 | 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table                         |     1 |
| 35 | 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table               |     1 |
| 36 | 2016_06_01_000001_create_oauth_auth_codes_table              |     1 |
| 37 | 2016_06_01_000002_create_oauth_access_tokens_table           |     1 |
| 38 | 2016_06_01_000003_create_oauth_refresh_tokens_table          |     1 |
| 39 | 2016_06_01_000004_create_oauth_clients_table                 |     1 |
| 40 | 2016_06_01_000005_create_oauth_personal_access_clients_table |     1 |
| 41 | 2018_12_30_232223_create_table_entreprises                   |     1 |
| 42 | 2018_12_30_232703_create_table_dossiers                      |     1 |
| 43 | 2018_12_30_232823_create_table_type_entreprises              |     1 |
| 44 | 2018_12_30_232906_create_table_groups                        |     1 |
| 45 | 2018_12_30_232922_create_table_menus                         |     1 |
| 46 | 2019_01_01_160217_create_table_cips                          |     1 |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

So the first 7 migrations are for Laravel, including Passport, which I don't need to modify. But Now, If I want to change `entreprises` migrations, then I need to rollback. All migrations are batch 1, so all tables will be lost, including passport clients and token. Even if I migrate in 2 times, let's say `entreprises` migration has batch 2, I can safely rollback, but I can't use command like `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` that will rollback the 2 batches.

Is there a way like updating some migrations batch to `0` or `-1` or `NULL` that could :

1. Ignore rollback for those migrations
2. Ignore migrate again for those migrations?

It's for development only as production won't need to rollback with existing data.

Comment: This article has a few methods that might get you what you want: [Rollback one specific migration in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287896/rollback-one-specific-migration-in-laravel)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `--path` answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38160720/5565544 is very useful. As it only migrate or rollback the specified path.