# how to roll back Laravel command

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have run the following Laravel command `PHP artisan make: migration add_category_id_to_posts` but I need to run the following command as well `PHP artisan make: migration add_category_id_to_posts --table=posts` then I need to roll back the first command and run the second command. then How?

Comment: You can't roll back such commands. Just go ahead and delete migration file which is created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rollback one specific migration in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287896/rollback-one-specific-migration-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Fatima Mazhit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10828488/fatima-mazhit), this command cannot be rolled back.

Simply delete the newly created `add_category_id_to_posts` migration file and run `php artisan make:migration add_category_id_to_posts --table=posts`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the earlier created migration manually and run the same command again after making appropriate changes in your migration. Or simply run `php artisan migrate:rollback`, will do your task.

Answer (score 0):

**go to your database/migration/your migration**
delete the migration you recently created, and then run the command again like so:

```
php artisan make:migration add_category_id_to_posts --table=posts.
```

**note:** you can rollback your migrations if you migrate your migrations on the command : `php artisan migrate` then you can rollback by `php artisan migrate:rollback`